Отношение один ко многим в sqlite3
есть вопрос: мне нужно, чтобы один foreign key ссылался на несколько объектов одного primary key. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это возможно сделать в SQLite3.

Сделать foreign key в этих самых нескольких объектах
